# get value from textfile command

Tags: c#

I have a small problem that i can not figure out. I have a code that wil read a textfile. When i read the textfile there are commands in the file. This commands are for a pump that is connected to an serialport. So what i have to do is get all the commands en send them over a serialport. I can do this, But now i have to make a `wait(value)` command. The value of the wait command is always different. So i have to get the `value` of the wait command and then i will put the value of the wait command in to an `Thread.Sleep(waitvalue)`. So the `waitvalue` is the value from the wait command.

This is my code for reading a textfile:

```
Stream mystream;
        OpenFileDialog commandFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

        if (commandFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if ((mystream = commandFileDialog.OpenFile()) != null)
            {
                string fileName = commandFileDialog.FileName;
                CommandListTextBox.Text = fileName;

                string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
                foreach (string fileText in readText)
                {
                    _commandList.Add(fileText);
                }
                CommandListListBox.DataSource = _commandList;

            }
        }
```

_commandlist is a StringList. StringList is a function from my co worker, in this function you will have a list of strings. 
In the stringlist i'll put the text from the file.
And then i'll asign the _commandlist as the datasource of my listbox.

This is the code for running the command and is this part of the code i am trying to get the value from the wait command. But i cannot figure out how to get the value.

```
_comport.PortName = "COM6";
        _comport.Open();
        foreach (string cmd in _commandList)
        {
            if (cmd.Contains("WAIT"))
            {
                //Action

            }
            _comport.Write(cmd + (char)13);
            Thread.Sleep(4000);

        }
        _comport.Close();
```

In the `Thread.Sleep(4000)` i have to replace the 4000 with my waitvalue.

Part of the textfile:
RUN
WAIT(1000)
STOP
WAIT(1600)
RUNW
WAIT(4000)
STOP

Can someone help me with this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the structure of the WAIT entry in the file? Once you know that, you just need to split the string using Split, then Convert.ToInt32 on the resulting numerical string. Pass the resulting int into your Sleep call.

Comment: I'll edit the question, i'll put in an part of the textfile.

Comment: The wait command is an string, So yes i have to convert it to an int but i do not know how to get the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach (string cmd in _commandList)
{
    if (cmd.StartsWith("WAIT"))
    {
        //Action
    }
    _comport.Write(cmd + (char)13);
    int wait = 0;
    var waitString=cmd.Substring(cmd.IndexOf('(') + 1, 
        cmd.IndexOf(')') - cmd.IndexOf('(') - 1);
    if (Int32.TryParse(waitString, out wait))
    {
        Thread.Sleep(wait);
    }
}
```

**[EDIT]**

I'm not sure if I understand exactly the processing logic, but here's my best guess for the structure of the code.

```
// iterate through the commands
foreach (string cmd in _commandList)
{
    // check if the current command is WAIT
    if (cmd.StartsWith("WAIT"))
    {
        int
            wait = 0, // the amount of milliseconds to sleep
            startPosition = cmd.IndexOf('(') + 1,
            length = cmd.IndexOf(')') - cmd.IndexOf('(') - 1;
        // check if the length of the string between '(' and ')' is larger then 0
        if (length > 0)
        {
            var waitString = cmd.Substring(startPosition, length);
            // check if the string between '(' and ')' is an integer
            if (Int32.TryParse(waitString, out wait))
            {
                // sleep for 'wait' milliseconds
                Thread.Sleep(wait);
            }
        }
    }
    // current command is not WAIT
    else
    {
        // send it to the COM port
        _comport.Write(cmd + (char)13);
    }
}
```

Comment: small question, What is the wait in Thread.Sleep(wait). Because it doesnt know it. Or do i have to have to make a string or something? Sorry for asking but im still learning

Comment: I get this error: Length cannot be less than zero. Parameter name: length

Comment: Just to make sure: when the WAIT line is being read, the thread should stop. If the line is not a WAIT line, the command should be processed?

Comment: Thanks for all youre help